# Does the polynomial ring $R[x]$, over the ring $R$, require that $R$ is commutative and has a multiplicative identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

The definitions I have been working with in my Modern Algebra class do not require rings to have a multiplicative identity. I am confused about how to work with polynomial rings. In Judson and other books I have found online, they introduce polynomials by saying "we will assume $R$ is a commutative ring with unity for the rest of this chapter". Sometimes my professor will just write "Let $R$ be a ring" for problems pertaining to polynomials over rings.

My question: If $R$ is a ring (not necessarily commutative or has multiplicative identity), then does $R[x]$ form a ring? If not, what properties are required of $R$? Is it just identity?

Comment: Neither identity nor commutativity are necessary (although, of course, you should expect $R\left[x\right]$ to lose some properties, such as the universal one, if they are not assumed). Noncommutative $R$ are used in several places. You can actually have $R$ be a module instead of a ring; this too has its uses.